# Is application protocol a subset of TCP?

Tags: tcp

My question is related to a concept that really confused me while reading an introduction to network related topics. What is the distinction between application protocol and TCP, exactly?

What I don't understand is how something like an HTTP port is considered a part of TCP, but actually is connected to the web as an application. Isn't it then application layer data? How are they separate? For instance, isn't HTTP port related to specific applications, like the web, and totally separate from other application like a torrent? Then doesn't it correlate to application level?

Comment: It's kind of similar to a cat flap (those tiny doors people install on their doors so that cats can enter and leave the house freely). It's a cat flap but is obviously not part of the cat. It is part of the house. However it's called a cat flap because it is used by the cat. The HTTP protocol has no concept of ports. Just check out the HTTP specification. It assumes a serial connection to transfer data, there are no ports in the HTTP specification. Ports are part of the IP protocol (which TCP was implemented on top of). However ports 80 and 443 are **normally** used by the HTTP protocol.

Comment: @slebetman, "_Ports are part of the IP protocol_" No, IP has no concept of ports. IP can carry many different transport protocols, some of which do not use port numbers. TCP, UDP, etc., do use port numbers and are 16-bit port numbers, but they are not the same ports. For example, TCP port 12345 is _not_ UDP port 12345, nor is it SCTP port 12345. The port numbers are part of and exclusive to the transport protocol that uses the port number, even if another transport protocol uses port numbers in the same range.

Comment: @slebetman, nowhere in _[RFC 791, Internet Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791)_ for IPv4, nor in _[RFC 2460, Internet Protocol, Version 6 (IPv6) Specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2460)_ for IPv6 will you find any reference to ports. On the other hand _[RFC 793, Transmission Control Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793)_ for TCP says, "_TCP provides a set of addresses or ports within each host._" Ports are for _some_ transport-layer protocols.

Answer (score 7):

The relation between application layer protocol and transport protocol is similar to the relation between language and paper. Language describes the rules for content which can be transported using paper, but language is not a subset of paper. Similar HTTP describes the rules how specific data are transported using TCP, but HTTP is not a subset of TCP.

Comment: Thanks for great example. Is then if i understood correctly whole concept closer to many to many relationship. Where each protocol like HTTP can have relation to many transport protocols TCP/UDP, and each transport protocol can have relation to many different protocols one of which is HTTP?

Comment: @21CenturyBoy: Application layer like HTTP defines how the payload is structured, Transport layer like TCP defines how the payload is transported. The transport protocol could be changed while keeping the application protocol the same - as long as the transport fills the requirements regarding transport which the application protocol has. So HTTP could be transported with TLS (HTTPS) or it could be transported with SCTP. Switching to UDP instead is not that simple since it does not provide reliability and ordering as needed for HTTP.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: It's more "the transport protocol can be reused for many different application protocols".

Comment: @BenVoigt: both: a single transport can be used for different application protocols, a single application protocol might be used with different transports (sometimes with small modifications).

Comment: @BenVoigt That’s just a side effect of historical designs, not a practical limitation. Almost anything that runs on top of TCP could be pretty trivially ported to run on any other stream-oriented transport layer (for example, SCTP or QUIC), and almost anything that runs on top of UDP could be pretty trivially ported to run on any other message-oriented transport layer (for example, RDS or DCCP). The fact that this is not done regularly is a matter of issues with support for those transport protocols on the network and the communicating nodes, not an issue of application protocols.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn, the limitation is primarily the use of NAPT on IPv4 because that only supports TCP, UDP, and ICMP (see _[RFC 3022](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3022)_, "_Sessions other than TCP, UDP and ICMP query type are simply not permitted from local nodes, serviced by a NAPT router._". NAPT breaks the IP end-to-end paradigm, and stifles innovation. IPv6 restores the IP end-to-end paradigm because there are plenty of unique addresses that NAPT is not needed or used. In fact, the _experimental_ NAT RFC for IPv6 explicitly forbids NAPT, requiring a one-to-one NAT.

Answer (score 7):

> What i dont understand is how is it that something like HTTP port is
> considered as part of TCP but actually is connected to web as
> application?

It is not an HTTP port; it is a TCP port that IANA has registered for use by HTTP. See the *[IANA Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml)*.

Answer (score 4):

Each layer needs to interface to the layers above and below it. The precise details of these interfaces are not normally defined in network standards because they are not visible "on the wire" and because they nessacerally depend on the design of the system on which the network stack is implemented.

When a packet is received, each layer of the network stack must know how to deliver the data to the next layer. Ethernet has an "ethertype" field, 0x0800 is IPv4, 0x0806 is Arp, 0x86DD is IPv6, there are many others for non-IP protocols. IP has a "protocol" field which identifies the "transport" protocol, 0x01 is ICMP, 0x06 is TCP, 0x11 is UDP. So the Ethernet implementation knowsthat it needs to deliver a packet to the IP implementation which in turn knows that it needs to deliver it to the TCP/UDP implementation.

The interface between TCP/UDP and the application layer is a bit different, because rather than merely being the boundary between two layers in the network stack, it is normally the boundary between the operating system kernel and the applications that run on that kernel. In particular one system may be running multiple instances of the same application, and one client application may even want to open multiple logical connections to the same server application.

Each logical TCP connection is therefore identified by a combination of two IP addresses and two port numbers. When discussing packet formats we talk about "source" and "destination" addresses and ports, while when talking about implementations on a host we talk about "local" and "remote" addresses and ports.

In UDP things are slightly different, because the operating system does not track UDP connections, but the basic idea of their being two port numbers and the IP/port combinations being swapped when generating replies remains.

Servers generally run on a port number that is statically configured when the service is installed. Clients on the other hand normally use a port number chosen at random. In this way multiple instances of the same client can happily coexist on the same host and connect to the same server.

For most protocols there is a default port number, which servers will listen on by default and clients will connect to by default.

Answer (score 3):

In the interest of brevity, in the following answer I'm intentionally
giving a high-level overview here; especially the names of things may
differ from what you read in various sources, and this may be combining
certain concepts you see split apart elsewhere.

To review: we have basically three components in the communications you're
talking about.

1. The *network protocol,* which in this case is TCP, deals with
   transferring sequences of bytes between endpoints. It is of no concern
   to this layer if the sequence is `GET /foo HTTP/1.0` (which happens to
   be HTTP) or `MAIL FROM:<joe@example.com>` (which you may recognise as
   [SMTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol)); neither string has any meaning to TCP. In either case, those
   characters are sent and received, without loss, in that order.
2. The *application* protocol, which consists of sequences of particular
   bytes that have meaning to the application. `GET /foo HTTP/1.0` will
   have meaning to an HTTP server, but will be considered an error by an
   SMTP server.
3. The *address* of each endpoint, particularly in this case that of the
   server. Here this includes the address of the *host* (e.g.,
   `192.168.1.1`) *and also* the address of the application on the host
   ("TCP port `80`"). Together these make up the full address; having a
   port number along with the host address allows multiple applications to
   communicate on the same machine (e.g., you can have both an HTTP server
   on port 80 and an SMTP server on port 25).

Where I think your confusion has arisen is in not understanding that these
three things are separate and [*orthogonal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality#Computer_science). When you use the HTTP
application protocol, it remains the HTTP application protocol whether or
not you're using it with TCP, and regardless of to what address you're
sending the HTTP requests.

For example, if I write down `GET /hello HTTP/1.0` on a piece of paper and
hand it to you, and you then write down on another piece of paper

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK

Hello, world.
```

and give me that piece of paper, we have participated in an exchange using
the HTTP protocol, though we have used neither TCP nor IP addresses.

This mixing and matching of protocols and addresses is a regular thing in
the real world. The protocol used to communicate between a [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)) client
(such as the `docker` command-line program) and Docker server exchanges
ordered sequences of bytes to request various actions (such as, "start a
Docker container") is frequently used over both [Unix domain
networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) and TCP networking. If I configure my Docker server to
listen at both the Unix domain endpoint `/var/run/docker.sock` and the TCP
endpoint `192.168.1.1:2375` (i.e., that host address and port 2375), I can
send Docker protocol messages to either endpoint (each of which is using a
different *network* protocol) and communicate with the server. To use the
first one I set `DOCKER_HOST=unix:///var/run/docker.sock` in my [process
environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable); to use the second one I set
`DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.1.1:2375` in my environment.

For convenience, popular application protocols that can be run over TCP or
UDP often have a *default port* that is used if you specify an incomplete
address that does not include the port number.

Thus, the *partial* address given in the URL `http://192.168.1.1/foo` is
exactly the same address as given in `http://192.168.1.1:80/foo`, and in
both cases "TCP protocol" is also implied (because it's clearly an IP
address, and HTTP is not used over UDP). The same is true of Docker:
`tcp://192.168.1.1` is a partial address that really specifies
`tcp://192.168.1.1:2375`.

Note that the use of a default port when not specified in the address is a
feature of *the particular application* that's accepting an address
specification from you; it is not part of the application protocol itself.
Whether a default port (or any other partial or full default address) is
used depends on the application:

- For HTTP, the IANA has defined a standard for default port (as mentioned
  in [Ron Maupin's answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80406/44829)): if not specified, port 80 will be used,
  and virtually all HTTP client applications will use this default if you
  specify an incomplete address that's missing the port. But only if you're
  using TCP! You'll notice that the default port used for TCP is irrelevant
  in my example of a "paper-based" HTTP communication above.
- For Docker the default port when using the `docker` command-line client
  is 2375. This is not an IANA standard; this was something that the
  original developers of Docker came up with and coded into their
  application. As with many programs; the Docker client even lets you
  specify no address at all and has its own default complete address for
  that case (`unix:///var/run/docker.sock` is that default).

Comment: "HTTP is not used over UDP" – actually, HTTP/3 is used over QUIC, which is based on UDP.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann 1. Re-read the first paragraph. 2. "Based on UDP" obscures the key point about why HTTP is not used over UDP: HTTP requires a [stream-oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection-oriented_communication) and [lossless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliability_(computer_networking)) connection. Both TCP and QUIC supply this; UDP does not. The reason QUIC uses UDP instead of IP at the layer below it is merely to make it easier to implement on existing systems (it can be implemented in userland instead of the kernel).

Comment: The reason QUIC is based on UDP is because NAPT only allows TCP, UDP, and ICMP. NAPT stifles innovation of protocols like QUIC, which could be its own transport protocol without UDP, except for NAPT that is required because of the IPv4 shortage. With IPv6, QUIC could be a separate transport protocol. SCTP could be used instead of TCP and UDP in many cases, but NAPT does not allow it for IPv4, but it works well with IPv6.

Answer (score 1):

A network stack is organized in *layers* where each lower layer provides services for an upper layer. HTTP in the application layer uses TCP in the transport layer, which uses IPv4 or IPv6 in the network layer, which might use Ethernet in the data link layer.

Layers communicate with each other for their services but neither is part of another. Each has its distinct functionality.

A HTTP server listens on some TCP port in order to be connected to. The default TCP port is 80 for HTTP or 443 for HTTPS.

These Q&A might be helpful for you:

- [OSI Model and Networking Protocols Relationship](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6380/osi-model-and-networking-protocols-relationship)
- [OSI Layer Model](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/68466/osi-layer-model)
- [How do the Application, Presentation and Session layers of the OSI model map to TCP/IP's Application Layer and vice versa?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1632/how-do-the-application-presentation-and-session-layers-of-the-osi-model-map-to)

Comment: Thank you for great answer. Since im total beginner those answers linked are bit complex to me because i seem to be confused about basics. Specifically if http is application layer protocol how can we layer applications on top of application specific protocol? What does it mean to write https and send packet labeled like that to other computer does it mean other computer has https reading app which translates request and turns on other apps if requested?  Main problem seems to be that no matter where i go explanations are too confusing for me even if introductory i need foundation first

Comment: Applications (e.g. web browser and web server) talk to each other using application-layer protocols like HTTP. Sorry, but providing introductions or tutorials isn't on topic here, see the [help/on-topic]. There are plenty of videos and books around that do a good job mostly, but resource recommendations are explicitly off topic here for being opinionated and attracting spam, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason for your question is some misunderstanding:

Protocols like HTTP, FTP, SMTP, ... do not necessarily use TCP but they can also use different connection-oriented protocols such as SPX or NetBIOS.

The fact that TCP is the only of these protocols being used today makes you think that HTTP requires TCP.

In the "ideal OSI model" it is the idea that you can replace the upper- and lower-layer protocols.

IPv4 (layer 3), for example, can use different layer 2 protocols (for example Ethernet or PPP) and it can carry different layer 4 protocols (for example UDP or TCP).

And TCP (layer 4) can use different layer 3 protocols (namely: IPv4, IPv6 or IPX) and carry different layer 5 protocols (HTTP, FTP, SSH ...).

The same is true for layer 5: You can use different layer 4 protocols (such as TCP, SPX, NetBIOS ...) to carry HTTP traffic.

However, most of these layer-4 protocols are no longer being used today.

Answer (score 0):

TCP/IP has four defined layers, the application layer, transport layer, internet layer, and the link layer. Each layer does something with the data, then passes that data on to the next layer for additional handling. None of the layers deal with the data from the other layers directly, they just add or handle their specific part of the data and then pass it on.

Ignoring the real-world complexities involved, consider the following analogy. Let's suppose you want to write a letter to your friend in another country. First, you write the letter (application layer), put the letter into an envelope (transport layer), address the envelope (internet layer), and then put in the mail box (link layer). From there, the letter travels to its final destination via mailperson, then by post office, then by other means (e.g. trucks or airplanes), which then goes to the far side post office, then to the mailperson, then to the mailbox, and finally to your friend.

The TCP/IP design means that, as long as the boundary rules are followed, you can swap out one implementation of any layer with another without disrupting the entire stack. As an obvious example, the link layer might be: WiFi, Ethernet, microwave, IR, fiber, dialup, etc. The internet layer doesn't care how the link layer is configured, just that it needs to route data from point A to point B. It also doesn't care what data is in the packet created by TCP/IP, it's just routing data across the network we call the Internet.

So, you wouldn't say that one layer is a subset of another, they're all distinct layers with specific purposes. Each layer is a part of a greater whole that makes internetwork data transport possible. The four layers are all required for an application (ignoring some special cases, like pings), but those layers can be swapped in and out as needed for performance, convenience, cost, etc.

Comment: *Network layer* is an OSI term, corresponding to the internet or IP layer in TCP/IP. The one below that is the *link layer*, see [RFC 1122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122).

Comment: @Zac67 I've edited the answer to reflect that, although I don't think it really matters. In technical college, I was taught that the local level is called a network, and some resources, such as [this one](https://www.avg.com/en/signal/what-is-tcp-ip) agree with that nomenclature. The main point of this answer is that there are four distinct layers that each have a specific responsibility. At no point was I referring to the OSI model in this answer. Different people might call the same thing by a different name.